# magento 2 migrate data of specific date from magento 1

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, migration, magento2-migration-tool

I have setup Magento 2 store and migrated Magento 1 data to Magento 2 store using the data-migration tool.

> https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool

I have migrated data from m1 to m2 last week and from last week to till date in m1 18 orders placed and 34 customers are registered.

How can I migrate the customers and orders that placed in last week to till date only?

Is there any parameter or method to mention in map.xml file or any other file?

Comment: yes, please check our answer. Hope that'll help you.

Comment: @teja would appreciate if you answer.  You are cleaning questions that's appreciated but answer on question would be greatly appreciated.  so please answer it.

Answer (score 0):

After completed data migration in case if you want to do Delta migration then run following command on a command line.

> php bin/magento migrate:delta vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ce/1.9.2.4/config.xml

Delta is used for incremental migration. Incremental migration enables you to migrate only the changes made in Magento 1 since the last time you migrated data. These changes are:

- Data that customers added via storefront (created orders, reviews, changes in customer profiles, etc.)
- All operations with orders in the Magento Admin panel

Hope it'll help you.

Comment: @jack Please and let me know it's useful for you or not?

Comment: i am checking it.

Comment: I just checked delta will import customer,s orders, reviews, profile updates etc.  Will it import product, categories?

Comment: @jack No, Delta will not import product, categories.

Comment: is there any way i can import product, categories?

Comment: I did create test products and orders after first migration.  If i will do delta now then will it work?

Comment: getting that error [2018-04-28 13:00:40][ERROR]: Deltalog for customer_entity is not installed

Comment: @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd., How about products and categories then? delta not migrates it, any other possibilities?